# Questions on Mosek Fusion Power Cone example

Tags: optimization, conic-optimization, mosek

Just trying to understand the example given in Mosek Fusion handbook as shown
[image: here]

I'm not exactly sure how to convert 7.3 to 7.4 in terms of objective function. I understand the power cone $P_{3}^{0.2, 0.8}$ constraint gives $x_0^{0.2}x_1^{0.8} \ge |x_3|$ => $x^{0.2}y^{0.8} \ge |x_{3}|$
Similarly, $P_{3}^{0.4, 0.6}$ constraint gives $x_2^{0.4}x_5^{0.6} \ge |x_4|$ => $z^{0.4} \ge |x_{4}|$.

However, I failed to see how to convert the new objective in 7.4 back to the objective in 7.3. I.e. $\max x_3 + x4 - x_0$  =>??  $\max |x_3| + |x_4| - x_0$ >=?? $\max x^{0.2}y^{0.8} + z^{0.4} - x$

Can someone explain?

Also, in the codes, it has:
[image: constraint]

Why is one Var.vstack and the other is Expr.vstack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maximizing $f(x)$ is equivalent to

$$\begin{array}{ll}
  \mathrm{maximize} & t \\ 
  \mathrm{subject\ to} & f(x)\geq t \end{array}$$

where $t$ is a new variable that does not appear anywhere else, since it pays off to push $t$ as high as possible i.e to reach equality in the constraint. That is what happens with the extra variables in that model.

Var is used for a bit of efficiency because all argmuents are variables. You could use Expr throughout.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your explanation!

Comment: Hope you don't mind a follow-up question. In the equivalent formulation, it has $f(x) \ge t$. In the example given by Mosek, it has $x^{0.2}y^{0.8} \ge |x_{3}|$. Notice the absolute value here. Is it true that we can remove the absolute value on $x_3$ because $x,y \ge 0$? Thanks again!